# video js fullscreen button does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with the fullscreen function in Videojs (http://videojs.com). The video's are on http://www.filmgasten.com.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Please describe your problem. For example, there are some javascript error? what browser? etc.

Comment: When the video opens, the fullscreen-button does nothing, there is no error in the javascript.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem with iframe.

Take a look at Videojs support forums: [Issue #1](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1345-fullscreen-issues) [Issue #2](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1345-fullscreen-issues)
Just search for more on your favourite search engine.

For a fix, I would say try to embed video on page and do absolute positioning and not iframe.. Not sure if this solution would work for you.

Comment: Thanks! i've modified the fancybox plugin and add 'frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"' to the iframe. It works for most browsers